# AFNetworking design pattern for wrapping REST requests/responses as objects

Tags: objective-c, class, rest, design-patterns, afnetworking-2

I am working on an IOS project that uses AFNetworking 2.0 for REST communication. I am interested to know if there is a good design pattern for wrapping requests/responses as individual classes. I want to create a base class, say `AbstractHTTPRequest` that has basic completion code (i.e. was the request successful, checks etc) that will be common to all `AbstractHTTPRequest` derived classes.

One of the derived classes will be say a Sign-up request (`SignupHTTPRequest`) that derives from AbstractHTTPRequest. Then I want to have a "client" classes with methods corresponding to each request, say:

```
@interface MyHTTPClient
  (SignupHTTPRequest *) newSignupRequest...;
@end
```

I want to know if anyone else wrapped the `NSURLSessionDataTask` / `NSURLRequest` etc classes used by AFNetworking into a coherent set of classes like I want to do. It is important for me to encapsulate the whole thing (logic, data, etc) into a class, but so far most attempts have been completely messy and I am not happy with it. The messy bit has to do with the fact that most approaches imply two sets of completion blocks. One used by the generic class (`AbstractHTTPRequest`) for the AFNetworking completions, then another set for the code that uses the actual HTTPRequest. You end up with this nasty chain of completion blocks.

Any ideas?

R

Comment: I was just searching along these lines as well.. any luck on an approach?

Answer (score 0):

[Ideas...]

1)Elegancy. So you want to tag certain "classes" of code to always call some default convenience methods? Here's the relationship I see:

> In human terms I would "delegate" a task to always be done by person1 because his role is "defined" when working with "me."

Does creating a objective-c protocols for delegates help? I'm reminded of pretty Python decorators but can't quite translate it.

2)Did I read BTL's right that you were trying ...finally blocks to indiscriminately run the common-calls?